# Spinnaker hal config ci concourse master add mymaster --read-permissions=[] --write-permissions=[] supply values

Tags: concourse, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm trying to configure Spinnaker with Concourse CI on Kubernetes provider. Concourse and Spinnaker itself running on `concourse` and `spinnaker` namespaces in the cluster. Concourse `web` (the web UI) is internally accessible at `web.concourse:8080`. I tried following

```
hal config ci concourse enable
hal config ci concourse master add mymastername \
  --url "web.concourse:8080" --username test --password test
#  --read-permissions=[] --write-permissions=[] # how am I supposed to pass options
hal deploy apply
```

`--help` gives *A user must have at least one of these roles in order to be able to run jobs on
    this build master* which I don't fully understand.

`Team` field is grayed out in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I got at least the connection established

```
hal config ci concourse enable
hal config ci concourse master add mymaster2 \
  --url "http://web.concourse:8080" --username test --password test \
  --read-permissions=[*] --write-permissions=[*]
hal deploy apply
```

Spinnaker can access CI pipelines.